# Как сделать галерею изображений на Ларавел?

Tags: php, laravel, изображения, laravel5, gallery

При добавлении от 2-х и более изображений, поле в которое загружаю видит только 1 изображение, как это исправить?
Может есть хороший видеоурок для создания галереи на Ларавел ? Кто может помочь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

не совсем понял ваш вопрос но возможно это поможет, в форму там где `type="file"` добавьте свойство `multiple` что в конце должно быть `<input type="file" name="myfiles" multiple>`, а в сервере получите массив `myfiles[]`

Comment: Да, спасибо большое! Уже нашел данное решение... только пока могу добавлять... с редактированием и удалением пока мучаюсь

Comment: @ОлексійСлєпцов а что там мучиться? При редактировании галереи просто выводите чекбоксы напротив каждого изображения на удаление изображений. Т.е. у вас будет только 2 экшена - добавить изображения и удалить.

Comment: Только теперь у меня в поле - file - которое записывается в таблицу БД - попадает такая строка - QNuEZYIy.jpg,QFhHjJoO.jpg,zXAwGcdq.jpg

Которую я потом разделяю через запятую и прохожу foreach'em и вывожу каждую картинку. То есть при редактировании, может снова загонять их в цикл, проставлять чекбокс у существующих и добавлять новые ( к каждому также чекбокс ). А как мне допустим удалять тот участок с названием файла из поля, и оставлять существующий ? То есть останется в поле только 1 - zXAwGcdq.jpg , а остальные удалить( ну если добавлять новые - добавить )

Comment: я бы советовал использовать для картинок отдельную таблицу  и добавить поле например если картины для поста то post_id. в этом случае будет легче манипулировать данными (удалять по post_id , добавлять изменять)

Comment: .в вашем случае запрос будет такой (delete from post_images where post_id = 'post_id' and image_name <> 'zXAwGcdq.jpg') или (delete from post_images where post_id = 'post_id' and image_name in 'QNuEZYIy.jpg,QFhHjJoO.jpg')